# auxiliary verb after "and"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, conjunction-reduction

Shall we use the auxiliary verb again after "and" as in the following case?

> The data **has** been collected and **has** been proved to be significant.

or

> The data **has** been collected and proved to be significant.